# Unexpected behavior when iOS device switched from 12 hour to 24 hour time setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have an app that is formatted with military time (`HH:mm`). When the device is in 12 hour time setting the time field in the app is correct. For example, 5:00 PM shows up as 17:00. When I change the device setting to 24 hour time, the time field shows up as null. I decided to change the formatting in the app to regular time (`hh:mm a`). When the device is set to 12 hour mode, the time field shows up correctly as, for example, 5:00 PM. When I switch the device to 24 hour mode, the time field again shows as null. So it seems that no matter if the time is formatted as 12 hour time (`hh:mm a`) or military time (`HH:mm`), when the device is in 24 hour mode both show as `null`. The JSON data source is `"functionStartTime":"05:00 PM"` which is stored in Core Data with an Attribute name `startTime` and Type `Date`. The code is below.

```
NSDate * sTime = [object valueForKey:@"startTime"];
NSDateFormatter *sdf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSLocale *slocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[sdf setLocale:slocale];
[sdf setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
[sdf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *sTimeStr = [sdf stringFromDate:sTime];
NSLog(@"Start %@", sTimeStr);
```

Comment: Given such a simple requirement (store hour/minute), you might be better off using an integer (which counts minutes) in the database.  That would be quicker and simpler to process and simply require conversion of `"05:00 PM"` to this minute value (better still, get the people running the server to provide the time in this format).

Comment: `NSDateFormatter stringFromDate:` doesn't return `nil` unless you pass in a `nil` date argument.

Comment: The thing is, I know it's not passing a nil value because when the device is in 12 hour mode and pulling the value from the same field as when the device is in 24 hour mode, it gives a value that is not nil. It's the same code when in 12 hour mode and 24 hour mode, but it works in 12 hour mode but not 24 hour mode.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your code snippet with the following -

```
NSDate * sTime = [object valueForKey:@"startTime"];
// get the locale
[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
NSLocale *theLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

// set the formatter like this
NSDateFormatter *sdf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [sdf setLocale:theLocale];
    [sdf setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [sdf setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *sTimeStr = [sdf stringFromDate:sTime];
NSLog(@"Start %@", sTimeStr);
```

You'll also need some mechanism to check this whenever the app returns from the background, in case the user changes the time format 12/24hr in settings.

Comment: I tried it. I so wanted this to work, but still getting null.

Comment: Copied the code exactly like you have it and still getting null. Funny thing is I do have in the app where it calls [NSDate date] to get the time now and it does it correctly when the device is in 24 hour mode. But when it's pulling the time from the Core Data attribute, it's nulling out.

Comment: By the way, the code you provided works perfectly when the device is in 12 hour mode. But when the device is switched to 24 hour mode, it shows null. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I tried creating a static time (17:00) from NSDate and used that value instead of the value being pulled from Core Data and that worked both when the device is in 12 hour mode (5:00 PM) and 24 hour mode (17:00). So it seems that 24 hour mode does not like the way the date values are in Core Data... I think. I'm going to work some more with this and see what I come up with.

Comment: I changed the time format in the JSON data source to 24-hour format (`17:00`) from 12-hour format (`5:00 PM`) to see what results I'll get. When the device is set to 24 hour mode, this shows correctly as `17:00`. When the device is set to 12 hour mode, this shows as `null`. I even changed the time in the JSON to `5:00 PM` from `05:00 PM` but still shows as null when the device is in 24-hour mode. Has no one else run into this issue? So frustrating!